# How to Navigate any destination for action of header of drawer in navigation architecture

Tags: android, android-studio, navigation-drawer, navigation-architecture

Anyone please explain, How to define the action in Navigation architecture for header layout of drawer.

[image: snapshot]

Now, I need to set click of header of drawer and I set it to like this:

```
headerOfNavDrawer.setOnClickListener{
    //Here I want to navigate to editProfileFragment
    //But For navigation I need an action in nav arch graph.
    //Where to put action??
}
```

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-ui#add_a_navigation_drawer

Comment: I have already finished the full setup of the drawer. Issue is that, How to navigate an action in header layout of drawer for launch a fragment.

Answer (score 1):

You have two things you need:

1. A reference to the `NavController`.

As per the [Navigate to a destination documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-navigate), you can use `findNavController(R.id.your_nav_host_fragment)` where `R.id.nav_host_fragment` is the `android:id` you put on your `NavHostFragment` in your Activity's layout.

2. An action to go to the edit profile fragment.

For this, Navigation allows you to set up [global actions](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-global-action) - an action that is available from every destination in your graph. This is the correct way of triggering actions from UI provided by your activity.

```
<navigation xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/main_nav"
        app:startDestination="@id/mainFragment">

  ...

  <action android:id="@+id/action_global_editProfileFragment"
      app:destination="@id/editProfileFragment"/>

</navigation>
```

When using [Safe Args with a global action](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-pass-data#safe-args-global), this will generate a `MainNavDirections` class that has your action on it.

This means your completed click listener would look like:

```
headerOfNavDrawer.setOnClickListener{
    // Use the Kotlin extension in the -ktx artifacts
    val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment)

    // Now use the generated Directions class to navigate to the destination
    navController.navigate(MainNavDirections.actionGlobalEditProfileFragment())
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer!
I resolved this issue using `navController.navigate(resId)` and resId can be a action Id or a destination Id from navigation graph.
I resolved this from `NavController.java` class -> `navigate(@IdRes int resId)` method. It says **param resId an action id or a destination id to navigate to a destination**