# action cannot be found from the current destination

Tags: android, kotlin, android-navigation

I have very simple navigation and when I attempt to go to new fragment I get this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Navigation action/destination com.my.app:id/action_settingsFragment_to_profileFragment cannot be found from the current destination Destination(com.my.app:id/mainFragment) label=fragment_main class=com.my.app.main.MainFragment
```

`navigation`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_graphs"
    app:startDestination="@id/mainFragment">
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/mainFragment"
        android:name="com.my.app.main.MainFragment"
        android:label="fragment_main"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_main" >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_mainFragment_to_laundriesFragment"
            app:destination="@id/laundriesFragment" />
    </fragment>
    <!-- other fragments here...  -->
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/settingsFragment"
        android:name="com.my.app.main.SettingsFragment"
        android:label="fragment_settings"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_settings" >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_settingsFragment_to_newOrderFragment"
            app:destination="@id/newOrderFragment" />
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_settingsFragment_to_profileFragment"
            app:destination="@id/profileFragment" />
    </fragment>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/profileFragment"
        android:name="com.my.app.main.ProfileFragment"
        android:label="fragment_profile"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_profile" >
    </fragment>
</navigation>
```

`SettingsFragment.kt` (redirect code)

```
when (position) {
    0 -> {
        //....
    }
    1 -> {
        navController.navigate(R.id.action_settingsFragment_to_profileFragment)
    }
    2 -> {
        //...
    }
}
```

[image: one]

**Any idea?**

## Update

I've managed to redirect to `profileFragment` with following code, but when I hit back button it closes the app instead of back to `settingsFragment`

```
private fun GenerateItems(){
    when (position) {
        0 -> {
            //
        }
        1 -> {
            this@SettingsFragment.navigateTo(ProfileFragment())
        }
        2 -> {
            //
        }
    }
}

private fun navigateTo(fragment: Fragment) {
    val transaction =  (activity as FragmentActivity).supportFragmentManager
            .beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.fragmentFragmentId, fragment)

    transaction.commit()
}
```

**Any idea about back button issue?**

Comment: Did you try it with action, using directions?

Comment: @Eyosiyas what do you mean?

Comment: The one you use to pass data or arguments.

Comment: NavDirections action =
        SpecifyAmountFragmentDirections
            .actionSpecifyAmountFragmentToConfirmationFragment();
    Navigation.findNavController(view).navigate(action);

Comment: @Eyosiyas not sure if I understand you correctly but I have something like this as well `override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        navController = Navigation.findNavController(view)
    }`

Comment: Check this link https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-getting-started#ensure_type-safety_by_using_safe_args

Comment: @Eyosiyas thank you but I really don't understand what `SpecifyAmountFragmentDirections` or `actionSpecifyAmountFragmentToConfirmationFragment` are referring to.

Comment: When you use Safe Args it will automatically generate for you.

Comment: @Eyosiyas is that possible that you share an answer? cause honestly I don't see this conversation getting any outcome for solving my issue.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60140498/10944045

Answer (score 3):

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Navigation action/destination com.my.app:id/action_settingsFragment_to_profileFragment cannot be found from the current destination Destination(com.my.app:id/mainFragment) label=fragment_main class=com.my.app.main.MainFragment

The exception means that you are trying to use an action named as `action_settingsFragment_to_profileFragment` that can not be found in the current destination/fragment which is `MainFragment`

**As action name implies:** It's an action that you use to move from `settingsFragment` to  `profileFragment`, so can only use this action within the `settingsFragment`.

Note: The auto generated action name is just an indication for the source & destination, but it can mean something else if the naming is messed up.

Confirming that in navGraph:

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/settingsFragment"
    android:name="com.my.app.main.SettingsFragment"
    android:label="fragment_settings"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_settings" >
    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_settingsFragment_to_newOrderFragment"
        app:destination="@id/newOrderFragment" />
    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_settingsFragment_to_profileFragment"
        app:destination="@id/profileFragment" />
</fragment>
```

This part of navGraph is when you at the settingsFragment, and there are two actions where you can go from the `settingsFragment` to `newOrderFragment` fragment or to `profileFragment`; or even pop up the backstack to return to the previous fragment

If you really want to go to the `SettingFragment` from the `MainFragment`, then you need to create a new action in the `MainFragment` as there is no one there, like below

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/mainFragment"
    android:name="com.my.app.main.MainFragment"
    android:label="fragment_main"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_main" >

    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_mainFragment_to_laundriesFragment"
        app:destination="@id/laundriesFragment" />

    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_mainFragment_to_settingsFragment"
        app:destination="@id/settingsFragment" />
</fragment>
```

UPDATE:

> I've managed to redirect to `profileFragment` with following code, but when I hit back button it closes the app instead of back to `settingsFragment`

You need to add `app:popUpTo="@id/settingsFragment"` and specify the fragment that you want the back stack popup to when you click the back or parent buttons

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/settingsFragment"
    android:name="com.my.app.main.SettingsFragment"
    android:label="fragment_settings"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_settings" >
    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_settingsFragment_to_newOrderFragment"
        app:destination="@id/newOrderFragment" />
    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_settingsFragment_to_profileFragment"
        app:popUpTo="@id/settingsFragment"
        app:destination="@id/profileFragment" />
</fragment>
```

**To use the generated directions class:** dd `apply plugin: "androidx.navigation.safeargs"` plugin to the gradle module level

Add the class path to the `gradle app level`:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        def nav_version = "2.3.5"
        classpath "androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:$nav_version"
    }
}
```

Then `Build > Make project` to generate the direction class. and In navigation use the generated class

```
navController.navigate(SettingsFragmentDirections.actionSettingsFragmentToProfileFragment())
```

Also [check documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-pass-data#Safe-args) for more info

Comment: so what you mean is in order to my navigation work i need to add `action_mainFragment_to_settingsFragment` in my main fragment right?

Comment: Yes.. That if you want to go from mainFragment to settingFragment. And use navController to perform the navigation programmatically on some action

Comment: gotin to `settingsFragment` from `MainFragment` is not my problem, my problem is going to `ProfileFragment` from `settingsFragment` **PS:** I just tried your suggestion still getting same error

Comment: I've added screenshot.

Comment: You do that from the settingsFragment class?

Comment: do what? navigate `navController.navigate(R.id.action_settingsFragment_to_profileFragment)`? If so, yes I'm doing this from my `SettingsFragment.kt`

Comment: Yes... Which is in the  when block

Comment: yes that's inside my `SettingsFragment.kt` file

Comment: Do you get the same behavior when using the geneated direction class instea of the id of the action?

Comment: I haven't tried that how should I do that?

Comment: I've managed to make it work but there is small issue would you mind see my update?

Comment: still closing the app

Comment: It won't work unless you use the action id or the generated direction class

Comment: would you mind show me how? cause this was the only way I could make it work maybe your way can do the trick as well.

Comment: Because you avoided using the navGraph in your solution

Comment: please show me your way, it might be better than mine.

Comment: so far only way it works is my update part :/

Comment: @mafortis please make sure that you added the `android:id="@+id/action_settingsFragment_to_profileFragment"` in the NavGraph, setting fragment, and in java/kotlin let the IDE auto-complete the generated Directions class its names should look like `SettingsFragmentDirections`

Answer (score 0):

```
  if (findNavController().currentDestination?.id != R.id.addressDeleteBottonSheetFragment) {
            findNavController().navigate(
                AddAddressFragmentDirections.actionAddressFragmentToAddressDeleteBottonSheetFragment(
                    selectedAddressId
                )
            )
        }
```