# Kotlin Navigation cannot find fragments

Tags: android, kotlin, android-navigation

I have multiple navigation graphs for multiple activities but I always have problem with navigating to fragments by navController. It always return such errors **cannot be found from the current destination Destination**

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Navigation action/destination com.my.app:id/action_orderDetailFragment_to_driverMapFragment cannot be found from the current destination Destination(com.my.app:id/driverMapFragment) label=fragment_driver_map class=com.my.app.orders.DriverMapFragment
```

I've tried various amount of solutions from safeargs by using `Directions` also `navigate` by ids etc. they all end up with same error. It becomes frustrating to deal with navigations

`navigation screenshot`

[image: one]

`Fragment`

```
class OrderDetailFragment : Fragment(), View.OnClickListener {

    lateinit var navController: NavController
    lateinit var drivermap: Button

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        navController = Navigation.findNavController(view)
        view.findViewById<Button>(R.id.drivermap).setOnClickListener(this)
    }
    
    // other functions....

    // here suppose to redirect to "driverMapFragment" from "orderDetailFragment" along with "Order ID"
    override fun onClick(v: View?) {
        when(v!!.id) {
            R.id.drivermap -> {
                // (1) Returning Error
                val bundle = bundleOf("orderIDArgument" to orderIDArgument)
                navController!!.navigate(R.id.action_orderDetailFragment_to_driverMapFragment, bundle)

                // (2) Returning Error
                // val action = OrderDetailFragmentDirections.actionOrderDetailFragmentToDriverMapFragment(bundle)
                // v.findNavController().navigate(action)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

PS: To avoid unnecessary comments I have to mention that I do have safeargs in gradles.

`app level gradle`

```
apply plugin: "androidx.navigation.safeargs.kotlin"
```

`project level gradle`

```
dependencies {
  classpath "androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:2.3.5"
}
```

## Update 1

[image: two]

## Update 2

`Structure`

1. I have OrdersFragment where list of all orders are showing to user
2. As I was facing very same issue about getting details fragment from that list items what I did was creating new activity named it `OrdersActivity` in this activity I get order details by `OrderDetailFragment` (main fragment of the activity)
3. Now `OrdersActivity` has new fragment which I'm trying to show map of order (redirecting from `OrderDetailFragment` to `driverMapFragment`)

PS: I am aware that this structure is a bit messed up (mostly because I was forced to make `OrdersActivity` which I didn't want to, but same issue (error) made me to do it this way.

Now here is my `activity_orders.xml`

```
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="56dp"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    tools:context=".orders.OrdersActivity">

        // by default it loads `OrderDetailFragment` then its supposed to switch to maps fragment when button is clicked inside `OrderDetailFragment`    
        <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
            android:id="@+id/orderFragmentId"
            android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:defaultNavHost="true"
            app:navGraph="@navigation/order_detail" />
</ScrollView>
```

`OrdersActivity.kt`

```
class OrdersActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_orders)

        // make sure main fragment loads only once
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            supportFragmentManager
                .beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.orderFragmentId, OrderDetailFragment())
                .commit()
        }
    }

    private fun navigateTo(fragment: Fragment) {
        val transaction = supportFragmentManager
            .beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.orderFragmentId, fragment)
        transaction.commit()
    }
}
```

Comment: Please include your entire Activity's code and its layout

Comment: @ianhanniballake I've updated my code + some explanations

Comment: We need to see your Activity's code as well, not just the XML.

Comment: @ianhanniballake sorry, I added it now you can see it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `NavHostFragment`, you should not be using any `FragmentTransaction` at all - you're adding a second instance of your `OrderDetailFragment` that is outside of the `NavHostFragment`.

Remove all of that code from your `OrdersActivity`:

```
class OrdersActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_orders)
    }
}
```

Comment: Life saver <3 :))

Comment: Can you please see my very similar question here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67032216/action-cannot-be-found-from-the-current-destination

Answer (score 0):

You need to move the `<action` outside of the `<fragment`, it should be a child of `<navigation` tag.

Comment: Are you sure?? because that action is added by editor (i didn't type it) I drag arrow from fragment A to B and that's where android studio added it.

Comment: This is never the correct solution as it will cause two DriverMapFragments to be added to your back stack (the error is saying you've already navigated to the DriverMapFragment).

Comment: please see my update, somehow you're correct i guess

Answer (score 0):

I put `<argument>` element as child of `<fragment>` and not as child of `<action>`. Immediately I got to use ClassNameArgs by navArgs().

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/SecondFragment"
    android:name="com.example.easybrowsing.SecondFragment"
    android:label="@string/second_fragment_label"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_second">

    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_SecondFragment_to_FirstFragment"
        app:destination="@id/FirstFragment" />
    <argument
        android:name="website"
        app:argType="com.example.easybrowsing.Website" />
</fragment>
```